# How to get max "id" from MemoryStore?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am refering to the example [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Memory.html#id4). How do I get the max id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemoryStore` simply holds some arbitrary data, when I need to get max id, I'm iterating all elements:

```
var data = store.data
var maxId = 1
var idField = 'id'
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
  var row = data[i]
  if (row[idField] && row[idField] > maxId)
    maxId = row[idField]
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I am curious how the following line works: `if (row[idField] && row[idField] > maxId)`. Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: It also works if I just do `if (row[idField] > maxId)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that. You could for example sort the store based on ID and get the first element, for example:

```
store.query({ }, {
    sort: [{
        attribute: "id",
        descending: true
    }]
})[0].id;
```

In this example it's querying all objects inside the store, sorting them on ID (descending). This obviously means that the first element has the highest ID, so you can just get that item and retrieve the ID property.

The good thing about this is that it only uses the Dojo store API, which means that this will work on any store that implements the `dojo/store` API, for example `dojo/store/Memory`.

---

Another solution is to search the ID by yourself, you can do this the way Lukasz did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22659082/1915448), but if you use `store.data` it means that it will only work with the `dojo/store/Memory` and you're accessing a property you should not access.

So to search it by yourself you could use:

```
require([ "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/_base/array" ], function(Memory, arrUtils) {
    var maxId = null;
    arrUtils.forEach(store.query({}), function(obj) {
        if (maxId === null || (obj !== null && obj.id > maxId)) {
             maxId = obj.id;   
        }
    });
});
```

What happens here is that I go through each object inside the store and then I check if `maxId` is `null` (= it's unset) or if the object ID is larger than the `maxId` and if that's true, then we replace the `maxId` by the ID of the current object.